# Querying multiple rows from Oracle table using package

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I wrote a package to query rows from a table. This select query will call other functions and returns all the rows from table. But when i write a package with all functions and sprocs , my sproc with select statement gives me an error saying i cannot execute without into statement. But if i use into then it will return only one row. How can i retrieve all rows using oracle sp?

```
    Procedure GetData As 
BEGIN 
Select Jobid, JobName, JobLocation, JobCompany, X(jobid) FROM jobsTable; END GetData; 
END;
```

I had to change it to following make the error go away:

```
Procedure GetData As 
  r_Jobid jobsTable.jobid%type; 
  r_JobName jobsTable.jobName%type; 
  r_JobLocation jobsTable.jobLocation%type; 
  r_temp varhar2(10); 
BEGIN

  Select Jobid, JobName, JobLocation, JobCompany, X(jobid) 
   INTO r_jobid, r_jobName, r_jobLocation, r_temp 
   FROM jobsTable; 

END GetData; 

END;
```

Comment: Could you add in the exact error that you get?

Comment: your stored proc code would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a better approach to returning multiple rows from a function:

```
FUNCTION GET_DATA()
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS

results_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

  OPEN results_cursor FOR
    SELECT t.jobid, 
           t.jobName, 
           t.joblocation, 
           t.jobcompany, 
           X(t.jobid) 
      FROM JOBSTABLE t; 

  RETURN results_cursor;

END;
```

I agree with afk though that this doesn't appear to be what you really need to be using.  Here's my recommendation for using a cursor:

```
 CURSOR jobs IS
     SELECT t.jobid, 
            t.jobName, 
            t.joblocation, 
            t.jobcompany, 
            X(t.jobid) 
       FROM JOBSTABLE t; 

  v_row jobs%ROWTYPE; --has to be declared AFTER the cursor to be able to reference the row type

BEGIN

  OPEN jobs;
  FETCH jobs INTO v_row;

  IF jobs%FOUND THEN
    --do stuff here, per row basis
    --access columns in the row using: v_row.jobid/etc
  END IF;

  CLOSE jobs;

END;
```

Are you aware that this:

```
Procedure GetData As 
  r_Jobid jobsTable.jobid%type; 
  r_JobName jobsTable.jobName%type; 
  r_JobLocation jobsTable.jobLocation%type; 
  r_temp varhar2(10);
```

...means you defined local variables?  You won't be able to get information out of the procedure.  If you do, you'd need parameters, like this:

```
Procedure GetData(IO_R_JOBID IN OUT JOBSTABLE.JOBID%TYPE,
                  IO_R_JOBNAME IN OUT JOBSTABLE.JOBNAME%TYPE,
                  IO_R_JOBLOCATION IN OUT JOBSTABLE.JOBLOCATION%TYPE,
                  IO_R_TEMP IN OUT VARCHAR2(10)) AS
```

I use the IO_ to note which parameters are IN/OUT.  I'd use IN_ or OUT_ where applicable.  But the key here is to define OUT if you want to get a parameter back out.

Also - packages are just logical grouping of procedures & functions, with the ability to define constants scoped to the package.  The package itself doesn't execute any SQL - it's still a function or procedure that is executing.  God how I wish SQL Server had packages...

Comment: Are you aware that these are not parameters but local variables that you are arguing about? IN/OUT does not apply. Either that or original poster is wrong.

Comment: @jva: Thx, corrected.  Poor reading comprehension brought on by lack of sleep.

Comment: I have to do some comparision and perform business logic on some columns of my table and return that data to my C# program. So i used package to write functions for each BL and call them directly in select query and was trying to return that result and load in datatable. It had 1 million records and my SP is running forever...i had to kill it..

Answer (score 3):

You could use a pipelined function.  For this example I'm only fetching the ID columns, but you just need to add the others.

```
CREATE PACKAGE jobsPkg AS
  TYPE jobsDataRec IS RECORD ( jobid jobsTable.jobid%type );
  TYPE jobsDataTab IS TABLE OF jobsDataRec;
  FUNCTION getJobsData RETURN jobsDataTab PIPELINED;
END jobsPkg;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY jobsPkg AS
  FUNCTION getJobsData RETURN jobsDataTab PIPELINED
  IS
    output_record  jobsDataRec;
  BEGIN
    FOR input_record IN ( SELECT jobid FROM jobsTable ) LOOP
      output_record.jobid := input_record.jobid;
      PIPE ROW (output_record);
    END LOOP;
  END getJobsData;
END jobsPkg;
/
```

This function can then be used as a row source:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE( jobsPkg.getJobsData );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Cursor for multiple return results.  Take a look at [this article on using Cursors](http://www.fast-track.cc/t_easyoracle_pl_sql_cursor_for_loop.htm) for some details.

You could do something like:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR myCur IS 
        SELECT Jobid, JobName, JobLocation, JobCompany, X(jobid)
        FROM jobsTable;
BEGIN
  FOR resultRow in myCur
  LOOP
     --do your stuff here
  END LOOP;
END;
```